# How can I fix this Bootstrap layout issue?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that uses Bootstrap 3. My layout should follow the below:

1. On small screens, Display 1 input per row with the label stacked above the input
2. On medium devices, Display 2 input per row with the label to the left of each input
3. On large devices, Display 3 inputs per rom with the label to the left of each input
4. **Rows that contain a textarea, should always be displayed with one input per row**

I have this almost working with one small quirk. Everything works well with all of the elements lining up like the below on all bootstrap breakpoints up to `md` like this:

[image]

However, when I hit the `lg` breakpoint, the text area and it's label no longer line up with the other element like this:

[image]

Looking at the grid I've set up I can see why this happens but I cant seem to find a pattern that fits my needs without causing this issue. I know I can start hacking away with CSS like negative margins to force the layout but I feel like there is a better way.

How can I fix this?

#### [Here is a jsFiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/6g7ay27g/)

And the relevant HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="row">
            
        <div class="col-sm-12 input-row clone-icon text-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2  col-lg-2 left-on-mobile">
                    <label for="" class="control-label  ">Textarea</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10  col-lg-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control form-input"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-row clone-icon text-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-5 left-on-mobile">
                    <label for="" class="control-label  ">Input Field</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-row clone-icon text-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-5 left-on-mobile">
                    <label for="" class="control-label  ">Input Field</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
                
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-row clone-icon text-right">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-5 left-on-mobile">
                    <label for="" class="control-label  ">Input Field</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
            
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first **Input field** change the `col-lg-*` classes from 5 and 7 to 6 and 6. That will make its `<label>` tag to align with the one in the previous row.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 input-row clone-icon text-right">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4  col-lg-6 left-on-mobile">
            <label for="" class="control-label  ">Input Field</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8  col-lg-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo link here](http://jsfiddle.net/6g7ay27g/1/)

Comment: That does work, I was hoping to be able to adjust the textarea row rather than the other inputs though. Any way to accomplish that?

Comment: I believe this cannot be done. The `<label>` of the textarea is `col-lg-2` and to reduce it you only can change it to `col-lg-1` but that does not work either (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6g7ay27g/2/)).

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Darn

Comment: You can always make it like you want but not with Bootstrap grid. Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6g7ay27g/4/). The notion is to change the `.col-lg-2` and `.col-lg-10` with new classes (`.col-lg-1dot5` and `.col-lg-10dot5`) that have the desired width.

Comment: That worked, perfect and much cleaner than what I was about to do, Thanks Tasos!

Comment: Glad I helped, have a nice day!